# src FFmpeg Binary from Lambda Layers

Tags: python, ffmpeg, aws-lambda, subprocess

How do you point lambda to the FFmpeg static binary

This is my set up so far

[Input S3 Trigger -> Lambda -> Src Layer -> Output -> S3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylGzM.png)

[Lambda Code-----This Code works on my local Machine the Goal is to get it working on AWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3a1M.png)

```
import json
import subprocess


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement

    print("I am being Triggered")

    p = subprocess.call(
    'ffmpeg -r 1 -loop 1 -i "./S3_Input.png" -i "./S3_File.mp3" -acodec copy -r 1 -shortest -vf scale=1280:720 ep1.flv', shell=True)


    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html):

> Layers are extracted to the /opt directory in the function execution environment.

I'm not sure how you've packaged ffmpeg in your layer, but supposing the binary is at the top level, you'd need to reference it like `/opt/ffmpeg`. So your first argument to `subprocess.call()` would look more like:

```
'/opt/ffmpeg -r 1 -loop 1 -i "./S3_Input.png" -i "./S3_File.mp3" -acodec copy -r 1 -shortest -vf scale=1280:720 ep1.flv'
```

If the binary is nested deeper, eg. in a `bin` directory, you're reference it like `/opt/bin/ffmpeg`.

Comment: It still says it doesn’t see it. 
I ran ls on the parent directory and say the opt directory was empty even though my lambs console said the layers are connected

Comment: Make sure your layer is set up properly: download the layer and make sure that it contains what you're expecting it to contain

Comment: Thanks so much for responding. I did just that too. I went to s3 and downloaded the zip files, extracted them and they had the content I expected.

Comment: Here's a couple different but similar projects. Maybe these examples will help you figure your stuff out. They both include binaries and execute them in lambdas. These ones don't use layers, the executables are bundled with the main lambda zip file. One runs git (via bash scripts kicked off from Python) and the other runs headless chromium (basically google chrome, without a GUI).
1. https://github.com/WhiteHotLoveTiger/lambda-git  
2. https://github.com/WhiteHotLoveTiger/Headless-Chrome-Screenshots

Comment: Thank you! Checking them out now.

Comment: Thank so much! I ditched layers and packaged them myself in the zip file. I was using ffmpeg but the ffprobe binary took my zip over the 50mb limit so I ditched it. I didn't find how to package more than just the logic with the serverless framework so I let it do the compilation with it's 'package' cli command, extracted it's zip, added my static files to It, zip it again (NOT with the 'compress' option on the mac but following some comments under differrent answers here : )

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182032/zip-the-contents-of-a-folder-without-including-the-folder-itself  so there's no nesting that aws doesn't work with by default)

Comment: @MayowaDaniel ever figure out why this was happening? Running into this now while running a branch for a project in which this same approach works perfectly fine

Comment: Never found out why @ElleryFamilia. Haven't touched it again since then